# How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in c#?

Tags: c#, gps

I am working on a MVC 5 Application.

Let's say I have GPS Device and I want to use the GPS location in my application, what api / code should i use?

For Example if i have travel agency and i have 2 cars and both cars has GPS device the condition is  "if My GPS enable car stop more then 2.5 min on road  in that case i need a single ping from my Gps device."

Comment: It depends. Is it hardware attached to a PC? Is it a mobile system? iOS? Android? All those factors play a role in how to access the GPS device and use its data.

Comment: No this is not iOS,Android it's a  MVC 5 Application.

Comment: I'm not an MVC5 developer by nature, but what you're searching for HTML GeoLocation services. My quick search found this introduction into the topic with MVC5 http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/782/html5-geolocation-aspnet-mvc-part1

Comment: Are you looking for the Client or the Server GPS Location?

Comment: I am looking for  Client to server  interaction by GPS device. if My GPS enable car stop more then 2.5 min on road  in that case i need a single ping from my Gps device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the GPS location for use in a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799385/how-can-i-get-the-gps-location-for-use-in-a-website)

Comment: Be much clearer about the type of the application(s) and what kind of devices etc. Just saying 'MVC' is not enough.

Comment: Why negative vote ?

Answer (score 1):

Using MVC 5, you have a choice as to whether you do it server-side or [client-side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation). I'd suggest:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success[, error[, options]])
```

from JavaScript. Then:

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options)
} else {
  /* geolocation IS NOT available, maybe use a server side method! */
}
```

Benefits your servers as they have less work to do, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the browser ability (Geolocation API) to read the current position.

```
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude; 
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp